# cancel button must have a function

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm having a problem with this cancel button.

with these codes:

```
int deposit;
String dep =
   JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to deposit?\n\t$: ");
deposit = Integer.parseInt(dep);
```

an "ok" and "cancel" button should appear but whenever I click the cancel button, no response at all. All I want is that whenever I click the "cancel" button it should return me to the main menu, but how?.

the code:

```
private static void processDeposit(String num, int rc){
    int deposit;
    String dep =
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "How much would you like to deposit?\n\t$: ");
    deposit = Integer.parseInt(dep);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        null, "You have deposited $" + dep + " into the account of " + name);
    myAccount.setBalance(myAccount.getBalance() + deposit);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look too much javascript for me...

Comment: You probably need to put more code.

Comment: Be clear in what you are asking. Mention the Subcategories properly.  Cancel button event handler is needs to be written to close the input dialog.

Comment: I see. cancel button is empty right?

Answer (score 3):

If the user clicks cancel dep will return as null

So you can do:

```
 if(input == null || (input != null && ("".equals(input))))   
 {

         //what you ever you need to do here

 }
```

Comment: @AsakaGhurl put it immediately after the JOptionPane so you can check the return result

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static void processDeposit(String num, int rc) {
    int deposit;
    String dep =
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "How much would you like to deposit?\n\t$: ");
    if (dep == null || dep.equals("")) {  // cancel pressed
        JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose(); // close dialog
    } else {
        deposit = Integer.parseInt(dep);  // no else or try/catch = NFE exception
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "You have deposited $" + dep + " into the account of " + name);
        myAccount.setBalance(myAccount.getBalance() + deposit);
    }

}
```